# how can i select date from calendar with array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make reservation system for test with HTML, CSS, JS. I have dynamic calendar and i have array, i need to make active only this dates

```
const dates = ["2022-03-04", "2022-03-05", "2022-03-06"];
```

here is my code

```
const currentDate = document.querySelector(".current-date"),
    daysTag = document.querySelector(".days"),
    prevNextIcon = document.querySelectorAll("header img")

let date = new Date(),
    currYear = date.getFullYear();
currMonth = date.getMonth();

const months = ["January", "Februay", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

const renderCalendar = () => {
    let firstDayofMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 1).getDay(),
        lastDateofMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth + 1, 0).getDate(),
        lastDayofMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, lastDateofMonth).getDay(),
        lastDateofLastMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 0).getDate();
    let liTag = "";

    for (let i = firstDayofMonth; i > 0; i--) {
        liTag += `<li class="inactive">${lastDateofLastMonth - i + 1}</li>`;

    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateofMonth; i++) {
        liTag += `<li>${i}</li>`;

    }
    for (let i = lastDayofMonth; i < 6; i++) {
        liTag += `<li class="inactive">${i - lastDayofMonth + 1}</li>`;

    }


    currentDate.innerText = `${months[currMonth]} ${currYear}`;
    daysTag.innerHTML = liTag;
}
renderCalendar();

prevNextIcon.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currMonth = icon.id === "prev" ? currMonth - 1 : currMonth + 1;
        if (currMonth < 0 || currMonth > 11) {
            date = new Date(currYear, currMonth);
            currYear = date.getFullYear();
            currMonth = date.getMonth();
        } else {
            date = new Date();
        }
        renderCalendar();
    });
});
```

and when i choose one of this array items(times) i need to get this information about which time i choose

i tried to change all time to this array, but then i cant get calendar dynamic.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: show the html code